# Android, onClick of Button fires before completing the built in animation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, onclicklistener, android-button

I'm new to android development. Developing a flipflop game.
On click button changes the colour and then it checks if the two turned buttons match or not.
I haven't added any animation below is my on click code.

```
fun onButtonClick(view: View) {
    val id = getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.id)
    val btnItem = getButtonItem(id)
    
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(btnItem.color))

    btnItem.isTurned = true
    btnItem.resId = view.id

    checkMatch()
}
```

and here is what each button looks like

```
<Button
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:id="@+id/btn02"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight=".50"/>
```

The problem is, when I click the button, the colour is changed after finishing the onclick execution, not sure if it's setBackgroundColor which is taking time or the onClick itself delays this. Even If i put a Thread.sleep right after setBackgroundColor it will sleep and don't even change the colour.
In checkMatch i want to match the turned cards and if they don't match i set the background colour back. but this all completes before even showing the hidden colour.
What should I do to complete animation and set background colour and then proceed further ?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: just use some boolean flags and enclose the checkMatch method in that if condition

Comment: what kind of if checks ? is there any way to know that the background colour changing animation has been completed ? as that's the built in animation and I didn't add any.

Comment: nope there are no methos as such changing colour is not animation and it's istant it dosent take time

Comment: flag as in after the colour has been set turn flag to true and check match only if its true or you can also make that it check button color and if it matches a particular color it will perform match